# Can i use angular kendo grid in my asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am currently using asp.net 4 with bootstrap 3 in my project, Here i used bootstap typeahead for autocomplete textbox so i want that once user select data from autocomplete list so that time it should do ajax call and angular kendo ajax call and should bind returned data in success event.
Below is my code:

```html
updater: function (item) {
                $('[id*=hdnHomeSearch]').val(map[item]);
                populateSearchItem();
                return item;
            }
```

This is my typoahead method where i am containing textbox autocomplete selected data by user.
and in populateSearchItem method i want to call angularjs kendo grid which is below:

```html
  <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Content/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/angularjs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="../Content/dist/js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/typoAhead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptions" k-pageable='{ "pageSize": 2, "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            columns: [{ field: "EmployeeKey" }, { field: "FirstName"}],
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Search.aspx/GetData1") %>',
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        return JSON.stringify(options);
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    total: "Total",
                    model: {
                        id: "EmployeeKey",
                        fields: {
                            EmployeeKey: { editable: false, defaultValue: 0 },
                            FirstName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true} }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

but after using this getting error text in console that is angular modulerr.
so this script method i want to use inside populateSearchItem method.
All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: make sure `kendo.all.min.js` has been loaded or not from developer console?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Thanks for your reply i checked kendo script in console and found that it was not loading due to missing closing element it happend because when i copied script from cdn it's not copied all so again i copied completed script but getting again angularjs Modulerr issue.

Comment: could you make a plunkr?

Comment: Sorry Pankaj, I don't know how to make a plunker but one good thing is that issue now i am not facing. Actually i missed one script that is angular kendo min after used this now that angular modulerr message not getting in console and able to call code behind method but now it is not displaying data.

Comment: I used my code behind method like this:  [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
        public static List<Student> GetStudent()
        {
            List<Student> studDetails = new List<Student>();
            Student sd = new Student();
            sd.UserName = "Vikash kumar";
            sd.Age = "32";
            sd.Address = "Bangalore";
            studDetails.Add(sd);
            return studDetails;
        } and in console message is showing cannot read property slice of undefined in kendo.all.min.js

Comment: Hey strange guys, i just remove data from schema and it's working the same in mvc application but the same i did in aspx page but getting error message in console that e.slice is not defined.

Comment: I can't guess what is going on..

Comment: Can anyone tell me i can use kendo grid with angular js in my aspx page, where the same code i mentioned above?